# AFNetworking 2 AFHTTPRequestOperation failure block stripping keys from error userInfo

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have just updated my app from AFNetworking 1.3.3 to 2.0.1, which required rewriting my network client that used to subclass AFHTTPClient.

I swapped out AFHTTPClient for AFHTTRequestOperationManager (I need to support iOS 6) and everything works fine apart from this:

The server gives me a JSON error string with the details of the error in:
error.userInfo.localizedRecoverySuggestion

However, this key (localizedRecoverySuggestion) is no longer in my NSError object.

Does anybody any idea how I can access it? Or what part of AFNetworking is stripping it out? The server is still sending it, it just doesn't make it as for as the error object in my POST: etc methods.

I've spent some time on this and I'm struggling to find where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

After a spot of debugging, it looks like the data takes the following path through AFNetworking:

1. AFURLConnectionManager connection:didReceiveData:
2. AFURLResponseSerialization validateResponse:data:error:

At which point it is thrown away.

So as a quick fix I just added an extra dictionary entry to that method where userInfo is created as follows:

```
NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey: [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

This is obviously a complete hack, but if anyone could give a pointer on how to accomplish this correctly, I'd be very grateful.